# How to properly use a vertex shader to morph a PShape

Tags: glsl, processing, vertex-shader

I'm trying to morph a PShape with perlin noise through a vertex shader.
So far i managed to do so by adding some noise to the `gl_Position`, but this affects all the elements in my scene, not just the shape.

I've already tried to put the shader call inside the push/popMatrix block or to call resetMatrix, but no success so far.

```
void init() {
    // Initialize Shader
    shader = loadShader("shaders/noisy-frag.glsl", "shaders/noisy-vert.glsl");
    shader.set("u_noise_amnt", 1.0);
    // Initialize Shape
    sphere = createShape(SPHERE, size);
    sphere.setTexture(loadImage("textures/marble.jpg"));
  }


void display() {

    shader(shader);

    pushMatrix();

    translate(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    rotateX(rotation.x);
    rotateY(rotation.y);
    rotateZ(rotation.z);
    shape(sphere);

    popMatrix();
  }
```

**Vertex shader**

```
uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 texMatrix;

uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform float u_time;
uniform float u_noise_amnt;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

varying vec4 vertColor;
varying vec3 ecNormal;
varying vec3 lightDir;
varying vec4 vertTexCoord;

float cnoise(vec4 position) {
  # perlin noise code
}

void main() {

 float displacement = 25.0 * (cnoise( normal.xyz + u_time ) - 0.5);

 gl_Position = transform * position + 1.0 * displacement;

 vec3 ecPosition = vec3(modelview * position);

 ecNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
 lightDir = normalize(lightPosition.xyz - ecPosition);
 vertColor = color;

 vertTexCoord = texMatrix * vec4(texCoord, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`resetShader()`](https://processing.org/reference/resetShader_.html) to restore the default shader.

If you want to apply a customer shader to a single object, then apply the shader right before drawing the shape by [`shader()`](https://processing.org/reference/shader_.html) and restore the default shader after drawing the object:

```java
void display() {

    // [...]

    shader(shader);
    shape(sphere); 
    resetShader();

    // [...]
}
```